# Transforming a data frame with one column to many columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, transform, reshape, transpose

Currently my data frame consists of 1 column with 2326 rows. I want to transform my data frame to consist of 11 rows. More specifically, my current data frame look like

```
John Doe
7
45
42
978
3
6
8
9
0
11
Sally Jenkins
2
```

etc.

I want my data frame to look like:

```
John Doe        7  45  42  978  3  6  8  9  0  11 
Sally Jenkins   2
```

Each person is a row and then their statistics are each a separate column in the row. Some people are missing a statistic so I can not separate based on the number of rows between each person's name.

I have tried using `t()` as well as `reshape(transform())`. Do you have any suggestions on where to go next?

Comment: What exactly have you tried? And what are these rows supposed to correspond to? Like if a person is missing a statistic, how do you know which one?

Answer (score 1):

**1)** One option is to create a grouping variable based on the presence of alphabets, `summarise` by creating a `list` output and use `unnest_wider` to change that `list` to a set of new columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df1  %>%
      group_by(grp = cumsum(str_detect(col1, "[A-Za-z]"))) %>%
      group_by(coln = first(col1), .add = TRUE) %>%
      slice(-1) %>%
      summarise(out = list(as.list(as.numeric(col1))))  %>%
      unnest_wider(c(out)) %>%
      ungroup %>%
      select(-grp) %>%
      rename_at(-1, ~ str_c('new_col', seq_along(.)))
# A tibble: 2 x 11
#  coln          new_col1 new_col2 new_col3 new_col4 new_col5 new_col6 new_col7 new_col8 new_col9 new_col10
#  <chr>            <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#1 John Doe             7       45       42      978        3        6        8        9        0        11
#2 Sally Jenkins        2       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA        NA
```

---

**2)** Or using `base  R` (No packages used)

```
grp <- with(df1, ave(col1, cumsum(grepl('[A-Za-z]', col1)), 
     FUN = function(x) x[1]))
aggregate(values ~ ind, stack(split(as.numeric(df1$col1[duplicated(grp)]), 
           grp[duplicated(grp)])),  FUN = I)
#            ind                            values
#1      John Doe 7, 45, 42, 978, 3, 6, 8, 9, 0, 11
#2 Sally Jenkins                                 2
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(col1 = c("John Doe", "7", "45", "42", "978", "3", 
"6", "8", "9", "0", "11", "Sally Jenkins", "2")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `DF` defined reproducibly in the Note at the end, ensure that `DF[[1]]` is character.  Then use `grep` to create a logical variable `g` with one element per input row which is TRUE for each heading and FALSE otherwise.  Then remove the headings and and split it up using the `setNames` to set the names of the resulting list.  Finally convert each list component to a numeric `ts` series as such series can be cbind'ed even if they have different lengths.  Now `cbind` those together and transpose.  No packages are used.

```
DF[[1]] <- as.character(DF[[1]]) 
g <- grepl("\\D", DF[[1]])
s <- setNames(split(DF[[1]][!g], cumsum(g)[!g]), DF[[1]][g])
t(do.call("cbind", lapply(s, function(x) ts(as.numeric(x)))))
```

giving:

```
              [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
John Doe         7   45   42  978    3    6    8    9    0    11
Sally Jenkins    2   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form is assumed to be:

```
Lines <- "John Doe
7
45
42
978
3
6
8
9
0
11
Sally Jenkins
2"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, as.is = TRUE, sep = ";")
```